# test value in template

Tags: python, django, templates

When I want to test value in my template I get the error:

```
Could not parse the remainder '=="0"
```

How can I test a value in template?

```
{%for eb in ebau %}
    <tr class="ligne-{{forloop.counter}}">
        <td id="cb-{{forloop.counter}}" class="cbox" >
            {% if eb.0=="0" %}
                <input type="checkbox" class="cb-{{forloop.counter}} " id="id-{{forloop.counter}}" checked="checked"/>
            {% else %}
                <input type="checkbox" class="cb-{{forloop.counter}} " id="id-{{forloop.counter}}" checked="checked"/>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td class="case">{{eb.0}}</td>
        <td class="case">{{eb.2}}</td>
        <td class="case">{{eb.3}}</td>
        <td class="case">{{eb.4}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `{% if eb.0 == "0" %}`. Mind the spaces.

Comment: You still output the same value in the if-block and in the else-block. That defeats the purpose of the comparison. Please read again the last sentence of my answer and reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing in a template you can use the built-in template tag `ifequal`:

```
{% ifequal eb.0 "0" %}
```

EDIT:
I just checked the documentation and this is now an obsolete way.
So stick with `==` and mind the spaces, as @aquaman suggested:

```
{% if eb.0 == "0" %}
```

However I'd strongly suggest to rethink the concept again and check if the logic can be placed in the view instead of the template.

Comment: Then you can close the question by accepting the answer.